# Sub-navbar in Bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I am trying to add a subnavbar to the normal navbar in Bootstrap 3.

In this sub-navbar I want a breadcrumb with the same layout as the navbar, but just under the normal "main" navbar.

I have already tried doing this by adding another `<div class="navbar">` element and removing some of the styling

```
.breadcrumb {
    background: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
}

.navbar {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

I have made an example on http://www.bootply.com/wxmTwKD8o3, but it seems not to be the right way to do it :-)

I would guess someone already did a sub-navbar, but I can't find any good examples.

Comment: You want it inside the navbar or outside?

Comment: I want something like http://blog.whatclinic.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/01/breadcrumbs.gif. So I want it inside the navbar

Comment: What don't you like about this breadcrumbs? Just reduce the ``min-height`` of the ``.navbar`` to 20px for example and thats it http://www.bootply.com/YtkonVEtDx

Comment: But it seems wrong to have two separate navbar elements, the margin under the navbar is wrong, and it makes a double border between the navbar and breadcrumb "navbar". But I don't know how to do it otherwise

Comment: Here you go http://www.bootply.com/qJB0tcQYrG

Comment: That looks like an answer to me, why not put it as one rather than a comment?